# need help while retrieving date from sqlite

Tags: xcode, sqlite

I have a problem while retrieving DateTime from sqlite3.
For Example to retrieve an int value we use

```
sqlite3_column_int(selectstmt, 1);
```

In the same way what function I have to use to retrieve the DateTime and how to convert it to NSDate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to retrieve it as text `sqlite3_column_text`, and convert it to date, using proper date format, if you want.

Comment: @Babji: Accept @Swapna 's answer. Her answer is more precise than mine.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
char* value = (char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectStatement, 2);
if(value != nil){
    NSString *dateTest = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:value];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"]; //sample date format
    NSString *formattedDateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:matchDate];           
}
```

Comment: NSString *dateStr=@"2008/02/03";
 NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
 [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy/dd/MM"];
 NSDate *date2 = [[NSDate alloc] init];
 date2=[dateFormat dateFromString:dateStr]; 
 After printing the log this is displaying the output as :2008/02/02 18:30 +000.But I need the output of 2008/02/03 only.

Comment: @Swapna, @Babji, In which format you've saved your date into the database?

Comment: You retrieve the date as text, from table and convert it to date.

Comment: @Swapna, @Babji, You are doing it correct. If you print a NSDate it will print like this only. It automatically adjusts the timezone offset when any date is printed. There is no problem in that.

Comment: Hello Swapna Kindly look at my comment.There I have used the DateFormatter

Comment: You first convert NSDate to NSString and provide the desired format using NSSDateFormatter. Hope its clear now.

Comment: Please go through my comment.There I have set the desired dateformat also.Eventhough I convert the date to String Finally get the string like this :2008/02/03

Comment: @Babji, you already have the date in the format in your `NSString *dateStr=@"2008/02/03";` line. What else you want? You want String or Date?

Comment: when I convert NSSring TO  nsdate I have to get the same thing

Comment: @Babji, I've already told you. What you have did as correct. When you print the date in NSLog it will print the whole thing (adjusting the time offset). Don't confuse yourself. If you want to verify whether you did is correct or not, you just convert the date to string and print it in NSLog. It will print in correct format.